# Can I prevent ICS browser from using CPU while in the background (without back-button exiting)?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, stock-browser, battery-life

I'm running ICS 4.0.3, and I notice if I have the Web app (default browser) open, but not in the foreground, it still uses a lot of CPU (25-50%), based upon the built-in Android Task Manager.  Other apps are using 0%.  Looking at my battery usage, the Web uses about 33%, even when my phone is inactive.

Is there any way I can prevent the Web app from using so much CPU when it is not in the foreground, without using the back button to exit?

I'm running on a Samsung Galaxy S2.

Edit:  If the best answer is to use a different browser, I am open to that suggestion.

Comment: Long press the Home key, to bring up the task manager and swipe it to the right, now at this point, am not sure if its to the left either... :D

Comment: As I remember, it was swiping either side, that removes it from the task manager list, and also, for killing the task.. hence my poor brain performance in recalling which is it... :)

Comment: Change to Chrome, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reason to believe that this may be a bug caused when the Web app has a large number of bookmarks.  In `System Settings -> Accounts and sync` I turned off `Sync Web` under my Google account.  Then I went to `Manage Apps`, clicked the All tab, and hit the `Clear Data` button.

This reduced the usage of the Web app to 1% when in the background.

When I enabled `Sync Web` to import all my Chrome bookmarks, then disabled it, the problem showed itself again.  I reproduced this problem twice.

Comment: That's interesting. How many bookmarks do you have?

Comment: @RichardBorcsik, I'm going to guess over 800.  My bookmarks were imported from desktop Chrome, which were imported from Firefox.  I just looked at my Firefox bookmarks, and I had 891.  I have a habit of bookmarking articles that I will never read again.

Comment: I have ~300 here without issues. If this turnes out to be the problem I suggest you move stuff that you'll never read to http://getpocket.com this way only the app that you never uses to never read the articles will be slow :) (that's how I do it.)